# For Kafka message compression, will it show up in the topics compressed?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am using Apache Kafka and am trying to enable compression on my messages. I see my records make it into my offset explorer, but am not seeing any of the messages compressed. I have the following configurations:

```
public ProducerFactory<String, String> factory() {
   Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
   props.put(ProducerConfig.COMPRESSION_TYPE_CONFIG, "gzip");
   return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(props);
}
```

I use this factory to generate a KafkaTemplate as such:

```
KafkaTemplate<String, String> kt = new KafkaTemplate<>(factory());
```

And then this KafkaTemplate is used to send off records to the broker. Is this the correct way of configuring compression for a Kafka Producer? Should I be seeing these messages compressed when they show up in Offset Explorer, if not how would I be able to tell if compression is going on? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Messages are automatically decompressed upon consumption, and offsets for individual messages don't change for compressed data

You'd be able to tell compression is working by looking at the disk storage used by the topic segments

Comment: How would I go about doing this? I'm using Offset Explorer to visualize my Kafka topics and records.

Comment: Go about what? Like I said, data is already uncompressed where you're viewing it. You'll need to SSH to the brokers, for example, to inspect actual log segment file sizes